# Angular 4: Handling ID Not Found

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, url-routing

In Angular, I understand how to use a wildcard routing to show a custom 404 page. However that only covers the case of a non-existing component.

What about the case where the user reached an existing component, but passed a non-existing ID?

For example `/widgets/12345` where `12345` does not exist in the database.
What is the best practice in this case to show a 404?

I managed to redirect the user to a 404 page by catching the error. But that does not seem right: you don't usually get redirected for a 404, you expect to stay on the same URL but with a 404 page instead.

Answer (score 0):

If in angular it was possible to send a 404 status error then it would be easier to handle this type of situation.
But, in angular there is no point of returning a 404 status error because in angular you're not actually making any http request while browsing through the component.

To get around this, you can use [Angular resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) to [Router Guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) find out whether the route data id is existed. If it is not existed then redirect to your **404 page**.

```
 @Injectable()
 export class checkIdExistence  implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router,
                private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private yourService: YourService) {
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, routerState: RouterStateSnapshot) 
    {
       return this.route.params
          .mergeMap(
           (params: Params) => {
              const newId = params['id'] ? +params['id'] : '';
              return this.yourService.checkExistence(newId)
                   .map((myInstance: any) => {
                       if (myInstance && myInstance.id ) {
                         return true;
                       }
                      this.router.navigate(['/404-url']);
                      return false;
                   })
                  .catch(() => Observable.of(false));
         });

    }
 }
```

Comment: " you're not actually making any http request while browsing through the component" - not sure I get this. I am going to `/widgets/12345`, which triggers my Service, which triggers an HTTP request to my server API, which returns a 404 error.

Comment: Your code includes `this.router.navigate(['/404-url']);`, meaning you are manually redirecting to the 404 page, meaning the URL bar will change to `/404-url` correct? If so, it does not solve the issue, I already have such an implementation ...